# SWT - Pan to Next Window Content

Tags: java, swt, pan

This isn't necessarily 'essential' for what I'm doing, but it would help to make the application look nicer.

I was wondering if it were possible to (instead of closing the window and opening a new one) pan from the current content in the window to the new content, preferably in any direction (up, down, left, right) of choice. If so, some code examples or a link pointing me in the right direction would be nice.

### What I mean by 'pan'

When triggered, the current `Control`s within the `Shell` gets moved out of view/off-frame, and new `Control`s come in from the opposite side, similar to panning a camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using TransitionComposite from Opal project:

https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/TransitionComposite

Alternatively You can create your own animation using AnimationRunner form Nebula gallery

https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php

For example:

```
    int FPS = 25;
    int DURATION = 500;
    AnimationRunner animationRunner = new AnimationRunner(FPS);
    Rectangle newBounds = new Rectangle(100, 100, 400, 400);
    animationRunner.runEffect(new SetBoundsEffect(composite, rectangle, composite.getBounds(), DURATION, new LinearInOut(), onStopRunnable, onCancelRunnable));
```

Comment: Both of these libraries seem to be what I'm looking for - I'll look into them.